# RegEx for matching GET request in Apache2 access logs

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to extract the URL inside a GET request found in the Apache2 access logs.

This is my code:

```
import re

x = "192.168.1.137 - - [07/Oct/2020:00:46:13 +0800] "GET /index1.php?command=CON4,0088888 HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win 64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/75.0.564.63""

url = re.search("\/index1\.php\?command=....\,.....", x)
if url:
   print(url.group())
else:
   print("No match found")
```

When I run this code, it tells me no match found, is there something wrong with my RegEx? I am new to Regex so I would really appreciate some help.
The exact URL that I want to get is : **/index1.php?command=CON4,0088888**

Comment: Will `index.php` ever be a different `uri`? Are you wanting to get any `uri` that a get is called against?

Comment: it will always be index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `regex` you have used does not allow for any variance in your check. As you are using `.` which will match one of any char. If the length were to change, your regex check would not be accurate.

---

If all `uri` will be `index.php` you can use

```
\/index.php([^\s]+)
```

- `\/index.php` - Will find `/index.php` exactly
- `([^\s]+)` - Will match all chars until the first white space

---

However if this will change, you can use the following to match any `uri` of varying length.

```
(?<=GET )\/(.*).php([^\s]+)
```

- `(?<=GET )` - will do a positive lookbehind to confirm `GET`  exists prior to our `uri`
- `\/(.*).php([^\s]+)` - will match any `uri` that ends in `.php` regardless of length, and then all chars until first white space.

---

```
import re

x = '192.168.1.137 - - [07/Oct/2020:00:46:13 +0800] "GET /index1.php?command=CON4,0088888 HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win 64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/75.0.564.63"'

url = re.search(r'(?<=GET )\/(.*).php([^\s]+)', x)
if url:
   print(url.group())
else:
   print("No match found")
```

Outputs:

```
#/index1.php?command=CON4,0088888
```

Comment: No problem, if you want an even more in-depth explanation of the regex included, check it out with information on every check it performs here; https://regex101.com/r/RmYf7z/1

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

x = '192.168.1.137 - - [07/Oct/2020:00:46:13 +0800] "PUT /index.php?command=CON4,0088888 HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win 64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/75.0.564.63"'

url = re.search('.*\s(.*)\sHTTP', x)
if url:
   print(url.group(1))
else:
   print("No match found")
```

output:

```
/index.php?command=CON4,0088888
```